# Change Scrollbar background from another view IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

**This is HomeView** 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rorUN.png)

When Someone tapped in 'Banking' button . Action  will load BaseviewController .

This is the button action.

***HomeViewController.m***

```
BaseViewController *clickbutton  = [[BaseViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BaseViewController" bundle:nil] ;
[self presentViewController:clickbutton animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**This is BaseView** 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHBZj.png)

> There is a scrollbar which will load every view . The scrollbar
>   background is Green . And change the background in next here is the
>   problem .

***BaseViewController.m***

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad{

   PriorityViewController  *obj ;

   UINavigationController *nav;

   obj  = [[ PriorityViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"PriorityViewController" bundle:nil] ;

   nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:obj];

   nav.view.frame = rect;

   [self.view addSubview:self.nav.view];

 }
```

When tapped 'Service Request'  .

```
  OtherBankTransferViewController *obj;
  obj  = [[OtherBankTransferViewController   alloc]initWithNibName:@"OtherBankTransferViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController  pushViewController:obj animated:YES  ];
```

This will load  same as like second image I uploaded here .
I just want to change my background color of the scrollbar 
I want to change scrollbar into black color .

I have no idea . If someone explain me !
Thanks in advance .

Comment: [myScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackcolor]];

Comment: After Tapped the service request it will loaded another view controller (navigation) .

Comment: In which view your scrollbar is and where do you want to change color?

Comment: When i tapped in 'Service Request' , A new view will emergence  . I want to change the background color of scrollbar this new view .

Answer (score 0):

**APPROACH 1:**
Instead of initialising scrollBar in each ViewController, why not alloc init it in BaseView Controller and pass instance of it to all View Controller.
Since now all ViewControllers will have same instance it will be easy to change background of the scrollBar.

**APPROACH 2:**
You can post notifications whenever you want to change the scrollBar color,
add observer for the notification you are posting and with the notification you can pass the color you want to be set for all scrollBar.

**Posting Notification** when you want to change color

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor blackColor] forKey:@"someKey"];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"TestNotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
```

**Adding Observer in viewDidLoad**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:) 
    name:@"TestNotification"
    object:nil];
```

Method to handle received Notification

```
- (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification{

    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    UIColor *backGroundColor = [userInfo objectForKey:@"someKey"];
    // assign this color to your scrollBar in each ViewController

}
```

**REMOVING OBSERVER in viewDidUnload**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"TestNotification" object:nil];
```